# Where can I find nice animations of flutter?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, flutter

Where can I find nice flutter animations/videos (other than *YouTube*) to add to a presentation without violating Copyright regulations ? It can either be for wings as well as blade arrays.

Are you aware of any *OpenSource* database on this topic ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YouTube is really your best bet - is there any reason you wouldn't be able to use one of the many [NASA videos](http://youtu.be/_oIYiFyyGC4)?

If you need a release for legal reasons NASA is famously liberal about granting rights to their research/educational videos - just contact then and you'll almost certainly get an official "Sure, you can use it!"

Comment: The link is dead due to the youtube account being terminated.

Comment: This play list is going to be enough https://youtu.be/5ZTK6kEtHag